# Checkstyle - can i change the `'(' should be on the previous line?` rule of MethodParamPad?

Tags: java, checkstyle

In checkstyle, The `MethodParamPad` generates message -

`'(' should be on the previous line`

In my code, for example it doesn't like

```
    schema.withProperty(propertyName, createStringType(propertyAnnotation, annotations.getAnnotationByClass
            (StringSchema.class)));
```

It wants:

```
    schema.withProperty(propertyName, createStringType(propertyAnnotation, annotations.getAnnotationByClass(
            StringSchema.class)));
```

Here is my checkstyle.xml file so far.

https://pastebin.com/2NXvzUjA

How can I make it so it enforces the first snippet, not the second?

Comment: For what it's worth, I think what it's telling you to use is better than what you want to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can literally enforce the second style since it would then fail on the call to `schema.getProperty`.

However, the rule has a `allowLineBreaks` parameter that you can set to true to make your code pass.
See http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_whitespace.html#MethodParamPad

```
<module name="MethodParamPad">
    <property name="allowLineBreaks" value="true" />
</module>
```

Comment: ok. i have added that and indeed i do not see the warnings anymore. which is fine.